# What is the correct or better server to use

Tags: server, updates

I live in the USA and was wondering what server I should use for updates, archive.ubuntu.com or us.archive.ubuntu.com.  What is the difference betweeen them?
TIA,
A4Skyhawk

Answer (score 2):

You can make yourself a list of the quickest responding mirrors by using the following command in terminal:

```
sudo netselect -v -s4 -t10 `wget -q -O- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors | grep -P -B8 "statusUP|statusSIX" | grep -o -P "(f|ht)tp.*\"" | tr '"\n' ' '`
```

This will give you at the end an output like this:

```
   94 http://mirror.network32.net/ubuntu/
   96 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
   98 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
  100 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

Side note: this tests the ping speeds and is not necessarily output the fastest servers but you can assume that you might be able to use the one with 100 rating and get good results.

As fkraiem pointed out the netselect package is not officially avaiable in ubuntu (still not sure how I got it then) but you can download the source code [here](http://github.com/apenwarr/netselect) and find its homepage [here](http://apenwarr.ca/netselect/). Or you can download the package [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/netselect/download)

Comment: `netselect` is not officially available in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Both repository server mirrors are okay to use.

You usually check what servers are near to your location, and out of those you select one with a high free data rate, low ping time from your location, and of course it has to be a mirror that is up to date.

You could look at [this official list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) and compare them yourself.

Alternatively, let the system pick the currently best server for you:

Open your **System Settings**, click **Software & Updates** and in the **Ubuntu Software** tab, open the **Download from** drop-down menu.

You will see a list of at least the entries **Main Server**, **Server for [your country]** and **Other...**. Select **Other...** to get the advanced menu.

A dialogue pops up that offers you a list of all registered mirrors on the left side. You could pick your favourite manually from there. But if you prefer the automatic way, click the **Select best server** button on the right.

Ubuntu will now make a few tests and compare the mirrors in your region. After a while (usually less than a minute) it has found the *currently* optimal mirror for you and selects it. Confirm and exit. When you get asked whether to reload the software lists, do that as well.